Two competing notions of average shortest path length?
Recently, I came across an article by Simon Dreyer, Antoine Genitrini and Mehdi Naima about two notions of average shortest path length...
Imagine a connected graph $G$ with n nodes.
Notion A To compute average distance (Definition 5.1 from the paper, page 9) you take the sum of all distances and divide it by $n^2$, the number of all node pairs in $G$.
Notion B Per contra, average shortest path length (Definition 5.2, page 10) is computed as the average of lengths of shortest paths taking into account their number.
I have an impression that in the literature, "average shortest path length" is a synonym to "average distance" due to some historic reason. Do you know any references of maybe another "googlable" name used in literature to denote the notion B that takes into account the number of shortest path length between nodes?
For example in the 4-cycle graph, depicted below the average distance is 1, but the average path length is 1.2!
A---B
|   |
C---D

Distances:
A to A = 0
A to B = 1
A to C = 1
A to D = 2
...

Lengths of shortest paths:
A to A = 0
A to B = 1
A to C = 1
A to D = 2 (path ACD)
A to D = 2 (path ABD)
...


Both concepts seem relevant to me. They are different, well defined, and, imho, well named in your question: you consider the average of all distances (A) and the average length of all shortest paths (B). It seems that the two concepts are mixed in the literature (including wikipedia), though.
